# Laravel accessor to convert category ids to category titles

Tags: php, laravel-4, relationship

Thanks for taking the time to help.

I am building a blog in which I can associate categories. I'm saving the associated cats in the blog table by id.

Eg: category_blog_id  =  1, 3, 9

I want to retrieve the categories by there title so thought the best approach was to write an accessor on the blog model.

Could someone point me in the right direction with this?

Should I add use CategoryBlog to the model and then explode the category_blog_id and run a foreach ver it?

That is what I have been trying, but it isn't working quite right yet and I wondered if there is a better, more Laravel-y way to do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the relation between `Post` and `Category` could be `many-to-many` because a `Category` can has multiple posts under it and also a `Post` could be in more than one `Category`. So, if this is the case then you should create three tables like:

Table - `posts`:

```
id  | post_title  | post_slug  | post_content | Others...
```

Table - `categories`:

```
id  | category_title  | category_slug  | Others...
```

Table - `category_post` (Pivot table/ maintains relation between posts and categories):

```
id  | category_id  | post_id
```

Then you need `two` Models as `Post` and `Category`:

```
// Post model
class Post extends Eloquent {
    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Category');
    }
}

// Category model
class Category extends Eloquent {
    public function posts() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Post');
    }
}
```

Create categories using something like this:

```
category::create(array(...)); // Input::all() (Mass Assignment)
```

Also you may create a `Category` using:

```
$category = new category;
$category->category_title = Input::get('category_title');
$category->category_slug = Input::get('category_slug');
// other fields (if have any)
$category->save();
```

Now create `Post` and attach categories:

```
$post =  new Post; // Assume that, this is the first post so id would be 1
$post->title = 'My Post'; // Input::get('post_title');
$post->slug = 'mypost';   // Input::get('post_slug');
// Assign other values like post_content etc then
$post->save();
```

Once the `Post` is saved then:

```
// Attach two categories with this post using category id
$post->categories()->sync(array(1, 2)); // These (1, 2) are category ids
```

So, now you have a `Post` and this `Post` belongs to to categories, in other words, this post has been created under two categories by syncing the the post and categories, you are actually making a relation between the post and two categories and these relational data will be saved in `category_post` table so according to this example you `category_post` table will contain something like this:

```
id  | category_id  | post_id
----------------------------
1   |      1       |   1
2   |      2       |   1
```

Now you may `query` using `Post` model to get all the posts with categories like this:

```
$posts = Post::with('categories')->get();
```

Also find a single post by id with categories related to it using something like this:

```
$post = Post::with('categories')->find(1);
```

You may access the related categories using this:

```
$post->categories->get(0); // first category from the collection
$post->categories->get(1); // second category from the collection
```

If you pass the collection of `Post` models to your view like this;

```
$posts = Post::with('categories')->get();
return View::make('post.index')->with('posts', $posts);
```

Then in the view you may loop all posts and categories like this:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
    {{ $post->post_title }}
    {{ $post->post_content }}
    @foreach($post->categories as $category)
        {{ $category->title }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

You may also use the `Category` model like:

```
// Get all categories with related posts
$categories = Category::with('posts')->get();

// Get a category using it's id with related posts
$category = Category::with('posts')->find(2); // Category id 2
```

This is the basic idea, read the manual ([Eloquent ORM](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models)) for more.

Comment: That is a great explanation. Thank you. It makes a lot more sense doing it this way as peterm also touched on. Right, back to the keyboard I go. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** ever store delimited values in the database! Instead introduce a many-to-many (pivot) table `blog_category` in addition to `blogs` and `categories` tables. It will allow you to normally maintain and query your data using the means that relational database gives you (e.g. JOINs).

The schema for such table may look like something this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE blog_category
(
  blog_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  category_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (blog_id, category_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (blog_id) REFERENCES blogs (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories (id)
);
```

A Laravel migration for such table may look like

```
class CreateBlogCategoryTable extends Migration {

    public function up() {
        Schema::create('blog_category', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->integer('blog_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('blog_id')->references('id')->on('blogs');
            $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
            $table->primary(['blog_id', 'category_id']);
        });
    }
    public function down() {
        Schema::drop('blog_category');
    }
}
```

Laravel Eloquent supports many-to-many [relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) out of the box:

In `Blog` model

```
class Blog extends Eloquent {

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Category');
    }
}
```

and in `Category` model

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    public function blogs() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Blog');
    }    
}
```

Now you can access blogs through categories

```
$blogs = Category::find(1)->blogs();
```

or categories to which a specific blog belongs

```
$categories = Blog::find(1)->categories();
```

Comment: Thanks peterm. I'm a bit of a newbie. Could you explain why I wouldn't save a delimited list? Are you suggesting I have three tables then, blog, blog_category and blog_category_pivot? Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. You'll end up having three tables with proper relationships between them. This will allow YOU to normally query your data. With delimited values you have no proper means to join data in your tables.